# How to differentiate a tap from a drag

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, touch, gesture-recognition

I'm creating an app and I'm trying to make it so I can drag a sprite (with a second sprite on top) around the screen, but if I just tap the sprite some other method should get called.

I got the dragging working fine when I touch the edge of my sprite, but when I try to drag from the middle of the sprite (where the second sprite is on top) the dragging doesn't work at all, but the tap gets called.

I know why is't doing this, tho, there's conflicting touches from both the sprits because the one on top is swallowing the touch before it hits the second one below it.

How would I be able to implement this where I want the sprite to drag if the finger moves, but I want the tap to register when only a tap is given (IE the finger didn't move on the screen)?

A visual of the sprites I'm working with (if it helps):
[image]

The yellow rune is a separate sprite from the stone underneath it (because there's animations involved).

```
--------Touch for the top sprite----------
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    lastTouchLocation = [RuneScene locationFromTouch:touch];
    BOOL isTouchHandled = CGRectContainsPoint([charSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation);

    return isTouchHandled;
}
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Tap received!");

}

------Touch for the bottom sprite--------

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    lastTouchLocation = [RuneScene locationFromTouch:touch];
    BOOL isTouchHandled = NO;

    // Check if this touch is on the Spider's sprite.
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([current.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = current;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune1.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune1;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }
    else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune2.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune2;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune3.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune3;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune4.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune4;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune5.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune5;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune6.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune6;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune7.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune7;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }else if(CGRectContainsPoint([rune0.runeSprite boundingBox], lastTouchLocation)){
        mover = rune0;
        isTouchHandled = YES;
    }

    // Stop the move action so it doesn't interfere with the user's scrolling.
    //[self stopActionByTag:ActionTagCastingLayerMovesBack];

    // Always swallow touches, GameLayer is the last layer to receive touches.
    return isTouchHandled;

}

-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint currentTouchLocation = [RuneScene locationFromTouch:touch]; 

    // Take the difference of the current to the last touch location.
    CGPoint moveTo = ccpSub(lastTouchLocation, currentTouchLocation);

    // Then reverse it since the goal is not to give the impression of moving the camera over the background, 
    // but to touch and move the background.
    moveTo = ccpMult(moveTo, -1);

    lastTouchLocation = currentTouchLocation;

    [self moveActionWithLocation: moveTo];
}

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (!current.isPlaced && mover == current && currentR < Rune6) {
        // Move the game layer back to its designated position.
        CCMoveTo* move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:curPt];
        CCEaseIn* ease = [CCEaseIn actionWithAction:move rate:0.5f];
        //ease.tag = ActionTagCastingLayerMovesBack;
        [current.runeSprite runAction:ease];

        [current setIsPlaced:YES];
        current.charSprite = [characters objectAtIndex:currentR];
        current.charSprite.position = curPt;
        //charSprite.visible = YES;
        [current performSelector:@selector(fade:) withObject:current.charSprite afterDelay:1];
        [current reorderChild:current.charSprite z:10];

        [self updateCurrentRune:currentR];
        [self updateCurrentCastNum:currentP];
        [self reorderChild:current z:10];
    }
}
```

I tried looking into the UITapGestureRecognizer, but everything I do to try to implement that never works. My layers/sprites won't let me add them as gestures. I also read something about CCGrstureRecognizer or something on the cocos2d forums, but I can't find any documentation on that class, nor can I find out how to actually use it...

Does anyone here know of a way to help me with my issue?

Comment: FWIW Kobold2D has a super-simple wrapper for gesture recognizers: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html#a35f245655ed7f7329f01a1500fc1e2b6

Comment: Ha I wasn't expecting the author of the book I was reading to comment on my question.

Comment: Then I guess I'm the Spanish Inquisition. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using (if CGRectContainsPoint) try using view's pointInside:withEvent: to return NO. That will cause the system to act like your view isn't even there.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please?

Comment: Sure. If you want the top one to be ignored and pass the touch on to the next just over-ride the view's pointInside:withEvent: method to return NO.